# how to comment and like FB status when we use FBGraph API (iphone)

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

In Facebook Graph API....

suppose there is a wall there ...

I want to put comment and like symbols there..

so I can comment and I can like any status which are there on the wall??

is it possible?? how??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see "publish" section in api reference.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

once you list the statuses or photos, you should have their ids

you can comment on a post via a POST request `https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments` with patterns `'access_token=...'` and `'message=...'`

or like a post/comment by requesting `https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes`
with `'access_token=...'`

i use curl in php and XMLHttpRequest in ajax for sending a POST request, you should know how to do it in iOS :)